# Run a function inside a nested class, from a different nested class where both are nested in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a piece of code looking like this, how would I be able to run `printInner2()` from the `printInner1()` function? Calling self.anything only shows things inside of the inner1 class, is there a way to "step up" to the next class level? Preferably keeping everything self contained so I don't have to init the class then call it internally.

```
class outer:

   class inner1:

       def printInner1(self):
           print("Inner 1")


   class inner2:

       def printInner2(self):
           print("Inner 2")
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Why are you nesting classes? Why do your functions not take a `self` parameter? Then they probably shouldn't be in a class at all. Nested classes are not a common python idiom, so it's hard to deduce what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is have `printInner1` and `printInner2` as class methods, meaning they belong to the class itself and not to an instance of the class, you should remove the argument self.

```py
class outer:
   class inner1:
       def printInner1():
           print("Inner 1")


   class inner2:
       def printInner2():
           outer.inner1.printInner1()
           print("Inner 2")

outer.inner2.printInner2()
```

If you need it to work with instances of a class you can do:

```py
class Outer:
    class Inner1:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent

        def printInner1(self):
            print("Inner 1")

    class Inner2:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent

        def printInner2(self):
            self.parent.inner1.printInner1()
            print("Inner 2")

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner1 = Outer.Inner1(self)
        self.inner2 = Outer.Inner2(self)


Outer().inner2.printInner2()
```

Although, there is probably a better way to go about it.
From the question it is really hard to deduct what is it that you're trying to do. And for most use cases this is bad practice and it's probably best to refactor the code.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for. I'm using nested classes for organization as I have a massive class with tons of different 'categories' inside of it. If using nested classes is bad practice, what would be a better way to go?

Comment: You could put your separated code into another python file e.g. 'utils.py' and then you can import it like any other library `import utils` or `from utils import some_function`. Btw, you should accept the answer if it solved your problem.